# .htaccess redirect addin trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have been using the following .htaccess for some time now to redirect non-https to https:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This week however an SEO expert told me this gives 2 redirects for links like this:

www.example.com/test

The first to http **s** ://www.example.com/test
The second to http **s** ://www.example.com/test **/**

Apparantly this is bad for SEO so I have tried adding a / to the last line, this doesn't work for files, e.g.

www.example.com/test.php => https://www.example.com/test.php/

I have done some searching but I can't seem to find a solution for both issues. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a check for the directory in the rule (one for directories and one for files):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# for directories without trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# for everything else
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, there's a good chance this won't work since the redirect from `/test` to `/test/` isn't happening via Rewrite, but via mod_dir's `DirectorySlash` directive. If you *really* want to just make this one redirect (I don't think the impact is that serious), then you can turn `DirectorySlash` off and have that redirect happen via mod_rewrite instead:

```
DirectorySlash Off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# for directories without trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# for everything else
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Add trailing slashes for directories that have them missing
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Strange, this seems to works perfectly on my test domain, but not on the domain to which this must be applied. I will also have the SEO expert take a look. Thanks for you quick response.